# vscode python autoformat indentation to 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces when saving the file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation, auto-indent

How do I make my source code of python to forced using 2 spaces indentation when clicking save file. ChatGPT code generated always produce 4 spaces that's why I asked this. I don't feel comfortable for 4 spaces indentation in python. I tried autopep8 formatter extension but it didn't help me.

Here is my current `.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
  "editor.autoIndent": "brackets",
  "editor.indentSize": "tabSize",
  "editor.detectIndentation": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "autopep8.args": [
    "--indent-size=2"
  ]
}
```

I expect from here:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

To the here after save the file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  asyncio.run(main())
```

Replying @Tim240 answer:
Here are I attached the screenshots, it seems same:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that pep8 mandates 4 space indents: https://pep8.org/#indentation

Comment: @gog then is there preference setup to make 2 space indents?

Comment: your screenshot shows "Also modified elsewhere". hover your mouse over that and tell us what it says. Is it just referring to your .vscode/settings.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `editor.formatOnSave: true` and then `Ctrl+Shift+P` type `Format Document` and then select `autopep8`, it worked!

Here is my current `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.autoIndent": "brackets",
  "editor.indentSize": "tabSize",
  "editor.detectIndentation": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "pylint.args": [
    "--indent-string='  '"
  ],
  "autopep8.args": [
    "--indent-size=2"
  ],
  "docwriter.progress.trackMethods": false,
  "docwriter.style": "Auto-detect",
  "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8"
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad Ikhwan Perwira, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the number of spaces in a tabulation, go to the settings (with Ctrl + , or Preferences<Settings).
In the "Commonly Used" category, you will see a "Tab Size" parameter.
Change the value (which is 4 spaces by default).

[image: settings]

You can also, when you are on your file, change this parameter in the "Spaces" option at the bottom of the screen:

[image: spaces option]

Comment: I did, but result nothing. It didn't do auto indentation to 2 spaces indentation in source code when saving the file.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira, have you tried the second technique that does not change the global settings but only for the current file ?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira, Otherwise, I advise you to check that vscode is up to date and reinstall it.

Comment: I updated my question, you can see I attached the screenshots, it seems fine.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira,
Sorry I don’t have an answer for your problem, I hope you will find a solution. However, I remind you of the convention: "For practical reasons, the most useful tab width is the one developers are most likely to set in their editor. For that reason, this PEP prescribes a four-space indentation."